# Interface always null

Tags: android

I am having an issue, cant figure out why the interface always null and really need your help. If I created a method to check the interface return, then it is OK, but the msgListener in side onMessage() method always null
Here the interface:

```
public class pacioWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
private static final String TAG = "===WsConnectivity===";
public WebSocket ws;
public MessageListener msgListener;

public pacioWebSocketListener(){
}

public interface MessageListener{
    void onMessageReceived(String message);
}

public void setPacioWebSocketListener(MessageListener mylistener){
    this.msgListener = mylistener;
}

@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
    super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
    Log.v(TAG,"onOpen");
}

   @Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
    super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
    Log.v(TAG,"pacioMsg : " + text);

    if(this.msgListener != null){
        this.msgListener.onMessageReceived(text);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"interface is null");
    }
}
```

And this the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String TAG = "===MainActivity===";
    pacioWebSocketListener myWS = new pacioWebSocketListener();

    TextView  tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        myWS.startConnection();
        myWS.setPacioWebSocketListener(new pacioWebSocketListener.MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG,"incomming: " + message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the `startConnection()` method? Can you give us any details on what WebSocketListener is?

Comment: @TheWanderer, startConnection is a method so I can send a command to a webserver via websocket. and WebSocketListerner is a class of okhttp3. https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/WebSocketListener.html#WebSocketListener--

Answer (score 0):

have MainActivity implement MessageListener()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements pacioWebSocketListener.MessageListener {

    public void onMessageReceived(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG,"incomming: " + message);
    }
}
```

and then just set the websocketListener like this

```
myWS.setPacioWebSocketListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried this before, but seems it didnt work, onMessagesReceived() never invoked when message comming